# Update Cursors without "FOR UPDATE OF" syntax issue

Tags: sql, syntax, cursor

Okay I have found the below code written by someone else in a file. My question is will this actually work as I thought with update cursors you had to include "FOR UPDATE OF" or "WHERE CURRENT OF" somewhere in the syntax in MSSQL

```
set @group_id_new = (select max(group_id) + 1 from x_dc_multgroups_stage001c)

declare cur_cont cursor for
(select cont_id from x_dc_multgroups_stage002b)

open cur_cont

fetch next from cur_cont into @cont_id

while @@fetch_status = 0


begin
--print @cont_id
update  x_dc_multgroups_stage002a 
set     group_id_new = @group_id_new 
where   group_id in (select group_id from x_dc_multgroups_stage002a where cont_id = @cont_id)

set @group_id_new = @group_id_new + 1

fetch   next from cur_cont into @cont_id


end

close   cur_cont
deallocate cur_cont
```

Comment: but, the cursor is not updated. So does it work? I can't see why not but you've got a chance of knowing. We don't have your schema or data.

Comment: I Just thought you couldn't use an update cursor without adding in FOR UPDATE OF into the code.. I'm not sure!

Comment: This code will work. I can't speak to the purpose of it, but assuming all the group_id_new variable is declared somewhere the syntax of it is correct. The cursor will be created and iterate to completion and will make appropriate updates with each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You have things somewhat backwards.

**If** the `UPDATE` was using the [`WHERE CURRENT OF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) syntax, then, yes, the cursor would need to be updatable. But that syntax isn't being used here.

At the point at which the update occurs, the only relationship between the cursor and the update is the `@cont_id` variable - but that variable could have been populated in any way you can imagine. It's not connected to the cursor in any way.